# Get author name on each post by joining tables

Tags: php, mysql, join

I'm having trouble joining 2 tables. I want all posts to have their author written under them.

**Table user** - idUser, FirstName, LastName and so on.

**Table post** - idPost, Subject, Text, Fk_user

Fk_user is a foreign key pointing to idUser.

I want First and Last name under each post.

All I get now is the same First and Last name of one person on each post.

```
<section id="reviews" class="page-section bg-dark gradient-servquick">
    <div class="pb-0">
        <div class="container relative">
          <?php
              $query="SELECT * FROM post ORDER BY idPost DESC";
              $result=mysqli_query($connection,$query) or die (mysqli_error($connection));
              $getUser="SELECT post.idPost, post.Fk_user, user.FirstName, user.LastName FROM post INNER JOIN user ON post.Fk_user = user.idUser";
              $resultUser=mysqli_query($connection,$getUser) or die (mysqli_error($connection));
              $extractUser=mysqli_fetch_array($resultUser);
              while($extract=mysqli_fetch_array($result)): ?>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2 align-center">
                    <h3><?php echo $extract['Subject'] ?></h3>
                    <div class="review review-text mt-0">
                        <p>
                           <?php echo $extract['Text'] ?>
                        </p>
                        <footer class="review-author text-center">
                           <?php echo $extractUser['FirstName'], ' ', $extractUser['LastName'];  ?>
                        </footer>
                    </div>
                </div><!--End Col-->
            </div><!--End Row-->
            <hr class="style-one">
            <?php
              endwhile;
            ?>

        </div><!--End Container-->
    </div><!-- End Slide Item -->
</section><!-- End Testimonials Section -->
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code does seem to be a little all over the place. For example, you still seem to query for posts twice, once with authors, once without, and then only loop around the posts, not posts with authors etc. The following should work, but not tested, please note the differences.

```
<section id="reviews" class="page-section bg-dark gradient-servquick">
    <div class="pb-0">
        <div class="container relative">
          <?php
              $getPost="SELECT post.*, u.FirstName, u.LastName FROM post p INNER JOIN user u ON p.Fk_user = u.idUser";
              $resultPost=mysqli_query($connection,$getPost) or die (mysqli_error($connection));
              while($extract=mysqli_fetch_array($resultPost)): ?>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2 align-center">
                    <h3><?php echo $extract['Subject'] ?></h3>
                    <div class="review review-text mt-0">
                        <p>
                           <?php echo $extract['Text'] ?>
                        </p>
                        <footer class="review-author text-center">
                           <?php echo $extract['FirstName'], ' ', $extract['LastName'];  ?>
                        </footer>
                    </div>
                </div><!--End Col-->
            </div><!--End Row-->
            <hr class="style-one">
            <?php
              endwhile;
            ?>

        </div><!--End Container-->
    </div><!-- End Slide Item -->
</section><!-- End Testimonials Section -->
```

Comment: I'm still not very good at php but I'm trying. I got lost in it and I was desperately trying to make it work. SQL JOINS are still new to me. You don't even know how grateful I am. It's working like a charm, thank you so much! Can I ask you one more question?

Comment: No harm in asking.

Comment: How do I proceed if I want a user to be able to edit his own post? I already have the code for updating but I'm not sure about the condition when I want an 'Edit' button to be only visible on his own post.

Comment: Usually on log in, there will be some reference identifying the user (often the user's ID) stored in their PHP session. Assuming you've got that, then in your loop you simply check whether that ID matches the author's ID (you'd need to update your SELECT to also return `idUser`).

Comment: Thanks for helping. you are awesome. How can I give you points for helping me?